# Charles proxy SSL issue

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

Facing this error SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations when trying to hit HTTPS request.Please suggest me what to do.I am running this first time so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You need to right-click on that request, and pick enable SSL Proxying.

Also, if you are working with NSURLSession and HTTPS, you need to implement this:

```
-(void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler {
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
}
```

If you don't, request just fail with broken handshake. You may also need to install Charles root SSL certificate. From top menu: Help -> SSL Proxying.

Comment: I've been using Charles for years and never noticed the *Enable SSL Proxying* command — great tip!